# How to convert a html select with optgroup to HTML Table

Tags: jquery, html, json, select, optgroup

I am having a select like this,

```
<select id="select_id" multiple="">
    <optgroup label="Group1">
        <option value="option1">OPtion</option>
        <option value="option2">OPtion</option>
        <option value="option3">OPtion3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group2">
        <option value="option4">OPtion4</option>
        <option value="option5">OPtion5</option>
        <option value="option6">OPtion6</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I want to convert this select to a HTML table. how can I convert this?

```
<table>
<tr><td rowspan="4">Group1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>option1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>option2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>option3</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan="4">Group2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>option4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>option5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>option6</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: my intention is to convert this select data to a html table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this question,

```
 var maketable ='<table>'
 $('#select_id optgroup').each(function () {
       var label_count = $(this).find('option').length;
       var rowsspancount = parseInt(label_count) + 1;
       maketable = maketable + '<tr><td rowspan="' + rowsspancount + '">' + this.label + '</td></tr>';
       $(this).find('option').map(function () {
       maketable = maketable + '<tr><td>' + $(this).text() + '</td></tr>';
   });
 });
 maketable = maketable + '</table>'
 alert(maketable );
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this: https://github.com/Jxck/html2json

Example:

```
var json = html2json(document.body.innerHTML);
```

If this particular library doesn't suit your tastes, a quick google search reveals that there's quite a few tools out there that can do this.

In general, you want to check for solutions that already exist rather than just homebrewing your own. If someone else has already done all of the hard work, why not take advantage!

Comment: hello, my intention is to convert this select data to a html table. so its seams this not helping me.